# save failed software RAID array

Tags: raid

I have a machine where the sata card failed and caused me to lose my raid array. I tested the drives externally and they are in good shape. I have moved the drives to a new machine (with enough onboard sata ports) and am attempting to get the array back up but I've run into problems. It's a RAID 5 array with 4 drives. It appears one of the drives is not in the array. I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and the current mdadm.conf is still the default. I have the old mdadm.conf information. I'd really like to preserve the data on the drives. Suggestions?

Here's what mdadm has to say:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md127 : inactive sdd1[2] sde1[4] sdb1[5]
      5860537608 blocks super 1.2
```

-

```
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bcde]1
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x2
     Array UUID : ef1b89aa:a2bbaab9:2ce4bdd0:47832afb
           Name : mediaserver:0
  Creation Time : Tue Aug  6 08:38:10 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3907025072 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 5860535808 (5589.04 GiB 6001.19 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907023872 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
Recovery Offset : 1799197544 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=1200 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 968168e5:6c695c7b:66a78ba1:9bccdc80

    Update Time : Sun Sep 29 16:09:54 2013
       Checksum : dd82d9a - correct
         Events : 47568

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : .AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : ef1b89aa:a2bbaab9:2ce4bdd0:47832afb
           Name : mediaserver:0
  Creation Time : Tue Aug  6 08:38:10 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3907025072 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 5860535808 (5589.04 GiB 6001.19 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907023872 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=1200 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 1da9199e:cc6fc424:128e502c:881d890a

    Update Time : Sun Sep 29 14:46:26 2013
       Checksum : 1923ec18 - correct
         Events : 47565

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : ef1b89aa:a2bbaab9:2ce4bdd0:47832afb
           Name : mediaserver:0
  Creation Time : Tue Aug  6 08:38:10 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3907025072 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 5860535808 (5589.04 GiB 6001.19 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907023872 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=1200 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 3688a662:e042319b:017fe47f:a73d04b2

    Update Time : Sun Sep 29 16:09:54 2013
       Checksum : 4f2dc2e7 - correct
         Events : 47568

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : ef1b89aa:a2bbaab9:2ce4bdd0:47832afb
           Name : mediaserver:0
  Creation Time : Tue Aug  6 08:38:10 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3907025072 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 5860535808 (5589.04 GiB 6001.19 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907023872 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=1200 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 173cc321:8c8b416a:635388f7:3dd0bb3e

    Update Time : Sun Sep 29 16:09:54 2013
       Checksum : e1b6266d - correct
         Events : 47568

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : .AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

With array stopped

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan -v
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sde
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda5
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sde1 is identified as a member of /dev/md/mediaserver:0, slot 3.
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 is identified as a member of /dev/md/mediaserver:0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is identified as a member of /dev/md/mediaserver:0, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is identified as a member of /dev/md/mediaserver:0, slot 2.
mdadm: added /dev/sdc1 to /dev/md/mediaserver:0 as 0 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdb1 to /dev/md/mediaserver:0 as 2
mdadm: added /dev/sde1 to /dev/md/mediaserver:0 as 3
mdadm: added /dev/sdd1 to /dev/md/mediaserver:0 as 1
mdadm: /dev/md/mediaserver:0 assembled from 2 drives and 1 rebuilding - not enough to start the array.
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

-

```
sudo mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md127 metadata=1.2 spares=1 name=mediaserver:0 UUID=ef1b89aa:a2bbaab9:2ce4bdd0:47832afb
```

based on a suggestion from the comments... I tried this and  got a new error.

```
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
mdadm: /dev/md127 assembled from 2 drives and 1 rebuilding - not enough to start the array.
```

ran smartctl on all drives and they passed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like sdc1 is not assembled. I am using mdadm as well, it does not work reliable using scan operations - I always assemble them manually. So try the following:

Make sure your array is stopped:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md127
```

Then reassemble your array with the following line:

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
```

Now check your status:

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md127
```

Your array will most likely being re-synced.

Comment: I got a new error

Comment: `sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1`
`mdadm: /dev/md127 assembled from 2 drives and 1 rebuilding - not enough to start the array.`

Comment: Try adding --force

Comment: Another possibility is to re-create the array with "assume-clean" ...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure the drives are clean though. I was in the middle of a grow when it failed. However, the data on the disks had not changed in over a month.

Comment: I tried force and this is what I got. `sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md127 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
mdadm: forcing event count in /dev/sdc1(0) from 47565 upto 47568
mdadm: /dev/md127 assembled from 3 drives and 1 rebuilding - not enough to start the array.`

Comment: definitely think that was a bad idea... they're all marked as spares now `cat /proc/mdstat Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md127 : inactive sdd1[2](S) sdc1[0](S) sde1[4](S) sdb1[5](S)
      7814050144 blocks super 1.2`

Comment: In the middle of a grow: This could be the reason why it tells you "not enough to start the array" - The grow is not completed thus the state is inconsistent. I have not come to such a situation since and can only  do guesswork now (that is try to re-create with "assume-clean"). Wish you good luck.